# Persistent WIFI Connection on iPAD

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios5

I need your opinion on the following issue:

We have an application which must be running (always on- never close) on iPAD 3, but we are facing automatic wifi disconnection/drop ( wifi sign will disappear from status bar) if we leave the device and app for about 30mins-1 hour. Auto lock is disabled from both setting and application code and the device is connected to a MacBook Pro (power source).

The Code:

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

This doesn't happen on all devices, we have the same iOS version (5.1.1) on all. This will only happen on iPAD 3 (iPAD 1/2/mini are fine).

Comment: You could create a timer to refresh the Reachability status every x mins, or to fetch a URL.

Comment: This is an enterprise application and it might not have connection to outside world! I have some other timers (1min/2mins and even every 3sec) to do some stuff, but all the communication might be limited to local network

Comment: You could still ping a local network resource then... else have a browse for keeping/maintaining active network/socket (local) connection alive, on this site.